# SwiftUI - Segment control using buttons not deselecting other buttons properly

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I am trying to make a custom segment control using a button array.

When a button is tapped, the correct value is passed to the main view and can be pressed multiple times without issue. The problem is that the previous button which was selected stays selected. The code below should work to recreate the issue. Thanks for the help.

[image]

Segment view

```
struct WaveTypeGridView: View {

var waveTypes = ["Beach Break" ,"Reef Break", "Point Break", "Rivermouth"]

@Binding var waveTypeSelected: String

@State var typeSelected: String

let columnSpacing: CGFloat = 5
let rowSpacing: CGFloat = 10
var gridLayout: [GridItem] {
    return Array(repeating: GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: rowSpacing), count: 1)
}

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        
        Text("Wave Type \(typeSelected)")
        
        ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false, content: {
            LazyHGrid(rows: gridLayout, alignment: .center, spacing: columnSpacing, pinnedViews: [], content: {
                
                ForEach(waveTypes, id: \.self) { type in
                    if type == typeSelected {
                        TypeItemView(selected: true, typeSelected: self.$typeSelected, name: type)
                    } else {
                        TypeItemView(selected: false, typeSelected: self.$typeSelected, name: type)
                    }
                }
            })//: GRID
            .frame(height: 18)
            .padding(.vertical, 8)
            .padding(.horizontal, 10)
            
        })//: SCROLL
        .background(Color(.systemGray5).cornerRadius(8))
    }
  }
}

struct WaveTypeGridView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
static var previews: some View {
    WaveTypeGridView(waveTypeSelected: .constant(surfDataTests[0].waveType), typeSelected: "Beach Break")
        .previewLayout(.sizeThatFits)

  }
}
```

Button View

```
struct TypeItemView: View {

@State var selected: Bool

@Binding var typeSelected: String

let name: String

func test() {
    
}

var body: some View {
    Button(action: {
        selected.toggle()
        typeSelected = name
    }, label: {
        HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 6, content: {
            Text(name)
                .font(.footnote)
                .fontWeight(.medium)
                .foregroundColor(selected ? Color.white : Color.black)
            
        })//: HSTACK
        .frame(height: 18)
        .padding(6)
        .background(selected ? Color.blue
                        .cornerRadius(8)
                        : Color.white
                        .cornerRadius(8))
        .background (
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
        )
    })//: BUTTON
 }
}

struct TypeItemView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
static var previews: some View {
    TypeItemView(selected: false, typeSelected: .constant("Rivermouth"), name:"Rivermouth")
        .previewLayout(.sizeThatFits)
        .padding()
        .background(Color.gray)
 }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason for not using the built-in Segmented control in SwiftUI?

Comment: @azamsharp It was so I could fit longer text and more segments without having to reduce or lose part of the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have made your state tracking more complex than it needs to be.  All you need to know is the currently selected wave type.  You don't need to track a separate `selected` state, since the button can determine this from it's own value and the currently selected value.

For the grid view you can just have a single `@State` property for the selected wave type (You could inject this as an `@Binding` if required).

Pass the selected break type and the view's target value to the `TypeItemView`

```
struct WaveTypeGridView: View {
    
    var waveTypes = ["Beach Break" ,"Reef Break", "Point Break", "Rivermouth"]
    
    @State var typeSelected: String = "Beach Break"
    
    let columnSpacing: CGFloat = 5
    let rowSpacing: CGFloat = 10
    var gridLayout: [GridItem] {
        return Array(repeating: GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: rowSpacing), count: 1)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            Text("Wave Type \(typeSelected)")
            
            ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false, content: {
                LazyHGrid(rows: gridLayout, alignment: .center, spacing: columnSpacing, pinnedViews: [], content: {
                    
                    ForEach(waveTypes, id: \.self) { type in
                            TypeItemView(typeSelected: self.$typeSelected, name: type)
                    }
                })//: GRID
                .frame(height: 18)
                .padding(.vertical, 8)
                .padding(.horizontal, 10)
                
            })//: SCROLL
            .background(Color(.systemGray5).cornerRadius(8))
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your `TypeItemView` you can create a computed property for `selected` based on the current value and this view's target value.

```
struct TypeItemView: View {
    
    @Binding var typeSelected: String
    
    let name: String
    
    private var selected: Bool {
        return typeSelected == name
    }
    
    func test() {
        
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            typeSelected = name
        }, label: {
            HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 6, content: {
                Text(name)
                    .font(.footnote)
                    .fontWeight(.medium)
                    .foregroundColor(self.selected ? Color.white : Color.black)
                
            })//: HSTACK
            .frame(height: 18)
            .padding(6)
            .background(self.selected ? Color.blue
                            .cornerRadius(8)
                            : Color.white
                            .cornerRadius(8))
            .background (
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
            )
        })//: BUTTON
    }
}
```

Now the whole control only depends on one `@State` item.

Comment: Thanks, Paul for your help and explanation